# Scrappy splash throws an error when handling the proxy argument

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, scrapy-splash

I use scrapy-splash on docker

Start line my docker

```
docker run -it -p 8050:8050 -v /etc/splash/proxy-profiles:/etc/splash/proxy-profiles scrapinghub/splash


log

2019-07-09 22:03:54+0000 [-] Log opened.
2019-07-09 22:03:54.216056 [-] Splash version: 3.3.1
2019-07-09 22:03:54.217509 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9.2, WebKit 602.1, sip 4.19.4, Twisted 18.9.0, Lua 5.2
2019-07-09 22:03:54.218375 [-] Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2019-07-09 22:03:54.219211 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2019-07-09 22:03:54.220048 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2019-07-09 22:03:54.325523 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':1881808514', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2019-07-09 22:03:54.441198 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2019-07-09 22:03:54.442271 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js cross-domain access: disabled
2019-07-09 22:03:54.624992 [-] verbosity=1, slots=20, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=90.0
2019-07-09 22:03:54.627025 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2019-07-09 22:03:54.628306 [-] Site starting on 8050
2019-07-09 22:03:54.629145 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f7f14c90cc0>
2019-07-09 22:03:54.630154 [-] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050
```

My url:
http://mysplashserver:8050/render.html?url=https://www.mysite.ru/c/355/clothes-zhenskaya-odezhda/&proxy=default.ini

My default.ini

```
[proxy]

; required
host=us-wa.proxymesh.com
port=31280

; optional, default is no auth
username=***
password=***

; optional, default is HTTP. Allowed values are HTTP and SOCKS5
type=HTTP

[rules]
; optional, default ".*"
whitelist=
    *mysite.ru.*

; optional, default is no blacklist
blacklist=
    .*\.js.*
    .*\.css.*
    .*\.png
```

I have error

```
{"description": "Incorrect HTTP API arguments", "type": "BadOption", "info": {"argument": "proxy", "description": "Proxy profile does not exist", "type": "bad_argument"}, "error": 400}
```

Please help me...

Comment: At which absolute path of your local system (not Docker) is your `default.ini`?

Comment: Yes, problems in here *mysite.ru.*, must be *mysite\.ru.*, i have forgotting back slash before point.